# "We have the right tires for your driving style."

Tags: road-vehicles, marketing

I saw an ad for a tire company today stating that they have the right tires for your driving style. When I buy tires I look for silent tires with long lifespan, good grip and most importantly a decent price. I've never even considered my driving style.

Is this just marketing-speak, or are certain types of tires better suited to certain drivers' driving *styles*?

Assuming other factors are the same (e.g. vehicle, roads, climate, conditions), does driving style influence the suitability of certain types of tires?

Comment: Well since @Oddthinking seems to think this is a Primarily Opinion-based question... flagging as that.

Comment: It could be edited into a more fact-based question in a number of ways... but since the original question was asked in 2011, it doesn't seem likely that we'll see that out of the OP.

Comment: @BenBarden Since the core of the question is: "should one take driving style into consideration when choosing tires" I find it obvious this is asking for opinion.

Comment: @MichaelK as-is, I agree.  The more fact-based approach would be asking about specific things like whether driving style has a significant impact on patterns of tire wear or other more dialed-in questions.  That would be the sort of edit that ought to come from the OP if at all, though, and I don't really expect that we'll hear back from him.

Comment: @BenBarden Well the answer to such a question is a quick "Yes". If you ride a lot in winter where they use grit on bike roads, that affects which tires you should pick. I always get myself puncture resistant tires for that reason... about 4 times as expensive, but **so** worth it for me. If you ride hard and aggressive, with much hard braking, that means you need tougher tires. If you are riding a road bike, you need road bike tires. If you are riding a mountain bike in the terrain, then you need mountain bike tires, but if you only stay on roads, you can use regular tires. And so on...

Comment: @MichaelK less blatant with car driving, where the road surfaces are a lot more uniform and the tires are more rugged to begin with.  Still, this is getting increasingly off-topic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80773/discussion-between-michaelk-and-ben-barden).

Comment: @MichaelK, where you drive and what you drive is not your driving style. Your driving style is how you drive, e.g. carefully or aggressively. If you drive aggressively, you reduce the lifespan of your tires and good grip becomes very important, as it could easily become the difference between life and death. However, a tire with good grip and long lifespan is also desirable for someone that drives carefully. It doesn't seem like the best tire for your vehicle would change based on your driving style. I also don't see how anyone could conclude that this question is opinion based or off-topic.

Comment: @ErikB **When** I drive is definitely part of my driving style. This year I did not get my summer tires on until well into May because I simply was not driving very much and had no need to swap them out.